Why does OWL-RL restrict Datatypes
The OWL-RL spec limits OWL's Datatypes to a pre-defined list (shortened for brevity):

rdf:PlainLiteral
rdf:XMLLiteral
rdfs:Literal
xsd:decimal
xsd:integer
xsd:nonNegativeInteger
xsd:nonPositiveInteger
xsd:positiveInteger
xsd:negativeInteger
...
xsd:anyURI
xsd:dateTime
xsd:dateTimeStamp

What is the advantage of limiting them in this way?  I'm not seeing an operation which cares about the datatype, so I don't see what the reason would be for limiting it.

those are built-in datatypes, same holds for OWL 2 DL in general. Ontology consistency check without knowing the lexical space of a datatype would be impossible, no?

@UninformedUser I see.  I had been thinking entirely of structural equality from the syntactic spec, not the direct semantics (It took me a while to find the subtle text that suggests Literals are compared semantically).  Makes it tricky if one wishes to use things like a Vector datatype or a Matrix datatype.
